# Insert json as a record to PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a table in Postgres that looks something like:

```
TABLE Product (
    id serial,
    name varchar(512),
    price numeric,
    ...
)
```

I am trying to create a procedure that would take an array of json objects and insert each element as a row into the table.

I am doing something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_into_product(entries json[]) 
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
   DECLARE _elem json;
   BEGIN
    FOREACH _elem IN ARRAY entries
      LOOP 
        INSERT INTO product
           SELECT id, name, price
           FROM json_populate_record (NULL::product,
             format('{
                "id": "%d",
                "name": "%s",
                "price": "%f"
               }', _elem->id, _elem->name, _elem->price)::json
      );
      END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

And I'm getting an error `"column "id" does not exist"`

Is the problem here that id is serial, and in my json object it's an int? What's the right way to insert row from a json object here?

Comment: `json_populate_record` needs to be called with the `_elem` as the parameter. `format()` returns a string value, not a JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_elem` variable is already a JSON value, so you can pass that directly to the `json_populate_record()` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_into_product(entries json[]) 
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $$
DECLARE 
  _elem json;
BEGIN
  FOREACH _elem IN ARRAY entries
  LOOP 
    INSERT INTO product
    SELECT id, name, price
    FROM json_populate_record (NULL::product, _elem);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
;
```

But you don't need a LOOP or even PL/pgSQL for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_into_product(entries json[]) 
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
  INSERT INTO product
  SELECT (json_populate_record(null::product, u.entry)).*
  FROM unnest(entries) as u(entry);
$$
;
```